# cookie among kids probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have 15 identical cookies and 4 friends. I am going to give cookies to my
friends. In how many way can I do this if
(a) I give all the cookies away and there are no other constraints on how
many cookies each friend gets.
(b) I give all the cookies away and each friend gets at least one cookie.
(c) I don’t necessarily give away all the cookies and I do not require that
each friend get a cookie

Ans::
a. 816
b.364
c. (c+k-1 c ) , not sure how this will apply here...
please suggest for only option "c"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** (c) You really have $5$ friends, the $4$ you mentioned and yourself.

There are just as many ways to give some (possibly none) of the cookies to the $4$ as there are  giving **all** the cookies to the $5$.

Comment: In terms of equations, there are just as many solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4\le 15$ as there are solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=15$. Or in terms of friends, if you give $2$ cookies to A, $0$ to B, $4$ to $C$ and $1$ to $D$, you can think of it as giving the above numbers to A, B, C, D and giving the remaining $8$ to yourself.

Comment: It will be $\binom{15+5-1}{15}$, so $\binom{19}{15}$ or equivalently $\binom{19}{4}$.

Comment: yes i got  the solution, Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. The idea (extra kid, extra variable) is a useful way to turn an inequality into an equation. Crops up in Linear Programming also.

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 people in this example, your 4 friends and you. Each of your 4 friends needs at least one cookie so you have 11 cookies after that. Now, you distribute 11 cookies amongst 5 people. This can be viewed as the classical "Ball in Box" Problem.

There are 11 balls and 5 boxes, a line is used to mark the end of a box and the start of the next, there will be 4 lines. So the number of possibilities are:
$${11+4 \choose 4}={15\choose4}$$
$$=\dfrac{15!}{4!(15-4)!}=$$$$\dfrac{15!}{4!11!}=$$$$\dfrac{12*13*14*15}{4*3*2}=$$$$1365$$
$\therefore$ there are 1365 possibilities

Comment: I guess its not correct, I don’t necessarily give away all the cookies and I do not require that each friend get a cookie ..........So you need not apply at-least fundamentals here. 3876 is the answer.

Comment: oh sorry I misread your question >.<